# Connected App-Trusted IP Range for OAuth Web server flow

Tags: connected-apps, oauth

I am trying to understand the use of **Trusted IP Range for OAuth Web server flow** setting of a connected app but the documentation is not clear to me.

Does it override profile level IP settings? How does it affect the  **IP Relaxation** setting at Connected App?

Thanks for your insight.